# How Can I Flatten An AnyPublisher<AnyPublisher<>>?

Tags: swift, combine

I load endpoints from a RESTful server from which some are multipage. They are denoted by an 'x-pages' field in the header response. I want to create a publisher that will return all of the objects from all of pages as a single array.

There is a compilation error on the last return statement.

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyPublisher<AnyPublisher<[T], LoadingError>, LoadingError>\' to return type 'AnyPublisher<[T], LoadingError>'
```

How do I fix this "embedded" publisher?

```
import Combine
import Foundation

enum LoadingError: Error {
    case url(URLError)
    case decode(Error)
    case couldNotDetermieLastPageNumber(URL)
}

func multipageDataTaskPublishter<T>(for endpoint: Endpoint) -> AnyPublisher<[T], LoadingError> where T: Decodable {
    assert(endpoint.page == 1)
    let publisher = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: endpoint.url)
        .retry(1)
        .mapError { LoadingError.url($0) }
        .map { (arg) -> AnyPublisher<[T], LoadingError> in
            let (_, response) = arg
            guard
                let header = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                let xpages = header.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "x-pages"),
                let lastPage = Int(xpages)
            else {
                return Fail(error: LoadingError.couldNotDetermieLastPageNumber(endpoint.url))
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }

            let publishers = (1...lastPage).map { page -> AnyPublisher<[T], LoadingError> in
                let next = endpoint.for(page: page)
                return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: next.url)
                    .retry(1)
                    .mapError { LoadingError.url($0) }
                    .map { $0.data }
                    .decode(type: [T].self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
                    .mapError { LoadingError.decode($0) }
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
            return Publishers.Sequence(sequence: publishers)
                .flatMap { $0 }
                .reduce([], +)
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    return publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

I could add a Sink immediately after the guard to read the lastPage value when the multipage publisher is created. Then with the `let publishers = ...` section lifted out of map up one level, my Publishers.Sequence return value would be correct. But this seems wrong on many levels; split execution, not composable.

Additionally I realize that my implementation loads the first page twice. Splitting the pipeline and merging Data payloads later would be better and I want to get to that solution but I need to wrap my head around this problem first. If this is a hopeless cause, then so be it and any idiomatic Combine solution will be accepted.

Comment: use `switchToLatest`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `.map { (arg) -> AnyPublisher<[T], LoadingError> in` needs to be a `flatMap`.